# "Would remain" vs. "would have remained"

Tags: differences, future, conditional-perfect, perfect-aspect, future-in-past

What's the difference in meaning between the following two sentences?

> 1. He thought that he **would remain** young.
> 2. He thought that he **would have remained** young.

Comment: What do you think?

Answer (score 1):

"He thought that he would remain young." He may be young now, and thinks he will remain young forever. *Or* he may now be old, and this is a statement about what he thought in the past.

"He thought that he would have remained young." He is now old, and is reflecting on an erroneous belief that he previously held, that he would have remained young.